# VBA Conditional IF statement using WEEKDAY

Tags: vba, if-statement, conditional-statements, weekday

#### Screenshot of Excel Columns

[image: Screenshot of Excel Columns]

I am trying to write a conditional IF statement based on the day of the week.

- Column A has the date.
- Column AK has a weekend value.
- Column AL has a weekday value.

I need the correct value (depending on day of week) to flow into column AT. The code I came up with isn't working. All that's showing up in AT is the AK value. I'm pretty new to VBA, I'm definitely missing something. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Sub Weekday()

For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If Range("A" & i) = "=Weekday" Then 'This line of code doesn't work
     
Range("AT" & i).Value = Range("AL" & i).Value 'This line of code works
                                    
Else
Range("AT" & i).Value = Range("AK" & i).Value 'This line of code works

End If

Next

End Sub
```

UPDATE: the AK and AL values are both decimals, like 506.468 or 348.286

Comment: Range("A" & i) checks the value of the cell and not the formula.  Try Range("A" & i).Formula = "=Weekday"

Comment: Thanks for your help Sorceri. I did try that but still getting just AK value.

Comment: You need to use Left(Range("A" & i).Formula, 8)  otherwise the formula will be =Weekday(some date value or cell reference)

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, what does the 8 do? ie. Formula,8)

Comment: =Weekday is 8 characters long

Comment: got it, thanks, unfortunately, it's still giving me just the AK value.

Comment: when you are checking for weekday formula or are you checking for the formula or the actual day of the week?

Comment: What I intend is to check the date (A2) etc. if it's a weekday, it would copy the value from AL2 to AT2. If it's a weekend, it would transfer the value from AK2 to AT2. Hope that's clearer. I added a screenshot if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sorceri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBA formula for returning the day of the week is slightly different than the worksheet formula. Try

```
If  Weekday(Range("A" & i).value, vbMonday) < 6 Then
```

[Further information on this function and it's arguments.](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/weekday.php)

Comment: Thanks for your help TPhe, I'm getting a Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid assignment

Comment: Perhaps try this instead: If  Weekday(Range("A" & i).value) < 7 and Weekday(Range("A" & i).value) > 1 Then

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the compile error, the word Weekday is highlighted in the debugger.

Comment: @monk - post the entire line where you get the debug error and let us know what the error is. TPhe's answer is spot-on. I suspect it some other syntax related stuff.

Comment: Oh, apparently that compile error is due to the fact that you named your sub "Weekday" - which is the same as the function name. You should change the name of your sub to something else. @monk

Comment: Ha, that sounds like the type of mistake I would do. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I am getting a Run-time error '13': type mismatch AFTER the values are copied. other than that it works great! Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. You may wish to post a separate question about the run-time error message you are receiving.